# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\tempkey.rsa' is denied."

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

I was trying to deploy an IdentityServer 4 app with ASP.NET core 2.2 into IIS in my local machine (Windows 10) and get the error:

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\tempkey.rsa' is denied."

Its working with debugging mode but getting above while deploying in IIS.

Identity server 4 version - 2.3.2

Asp.net core 2.2

IIS 10.0.16

Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error and it was coming from the call to `AddDeveloperSigningCredential()` inside *configure services*. When I changed it to `AddDeveloperSigningCredential( persistKey: false )`, the error went away.

Here is entire function call block

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential( persistKey:false)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources( Config.GetApiResources() )
    .AddInMemoryClients( Config.GetClients() );
}
```

Comment: But I am getting Internal server error after adding persistKey:false

Comment: @HrishikeshTT my suggestion above was only for the Unauthorised Exception, I am not sure about other possible errors.

Answer (score 6):

Change the app pool identity to LocalSystem. Or give access to whatever app pool identity you are using to that location.

Comment: I tried a lot of other "fixes", but this fixed the problem for me! Thx!!!